Fourier Coefficient Estimation and Function Convergence
In my studies on $L^2$ spaces and Fourier analysis, I've come across this problem, which involves analyzing the convergence of a sequence of functions based on their Fourier coefficients. This problem is important because it relates to understanding the behavior of functions in Hilbert spaces, which is foundational in many areas of analysis.
Assume that there is a constant $C$ and a sequence of functions $f^{(M)}$ in $L^2([-\pi, \pi])$ such that:
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}(1 + |n|)(\ln(2 + |n|))^2 |\hat{f}^{(M)}(n)|^2 \leq C < \infty, \quad \text{for all } M
$$
Show that there exists a function $g(n)$ such that:
$$
\lim_{M \to \infty} \hat{f}^{(M)}(n) = g(n), \quad \text{for all } n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Furthermore, show that there exists a function $h \in C_0^\text{Per}([-\pi, \pi])$ such that $\hat{h}(n) = g(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and that the Fourier series of $h$ converges to $h$ if it is equal to $h$.
One approach could be to use the boundedness condition to show that the sequence $f^{(M)}$ is Cauchy in the $L^2$ space, and then use the properties of Fourier coefficients to establish the existence of the function $g(n)$. Does this seem like a valid approach?

What is $f^{(M)}\ ?$  Just a sequence of functions indexed by $M$ ? If so there is no reason that this sequence satisfies the Cauchy condition.
